# How would I determine whether or not to render the player over or behind a tree in a 2d top down game?

Tags: 2d, rendering, tiles

In games like Factorio, you might notice that when the player is at a certain coordinate relative to the tree, it renders in front of the player, thereby giving the effect that the player is behind the tree. My question is, how is this accomplished?

Here are some examples:
Behind a telephone pole:
[image]
In front of one:
[image]

Comment: Sure. One min and I'll add them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This effect is usually accomplished through sorting the draw order along an axis. In this case, the Y axis. Objects with the lower Y value (higher up on the screen) are drawn first. Objects drawn with a higher Y value are then drawn, overlapping the objects drawn earlier.

[image: Image of draw sorting]

In this example, the X value is unimportant;

On the left, the orange box is drawn first because it's y is less than the y of the green box.

On the right, the orange box has now moved down 10 units on the y axis and is now drawn after the green box because it's y is greater than that of the green box.